# How to search for a word in a variable string in jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have an array of data that I use to be able to fill my select, but I want to condition from jinja so that it only adds some specific data to my select.
For example:

in Python:
fruits = [apple 1,banana 1,grapes,orange,broccoli,carrot,potato 1]

in Html:

```
<select>
   {% for item in fruits %}
     **{% if sentence %}**
          <option value="{{item.fruits}}" >{{item.fruits}}</option>
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

What I want to do is that the select is filled conditionally if item has the value 1 start to fill it, any ideas that I can use in jinja2.
I was looking for something similar to indexOf but haven't found anything similar. any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the `in` operator to see if a string contains a substsring: `{% if "some string" in somevriable %}...{% endif %}`. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: maybe filter data before you send it to template.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition in the Jinja2 template and show only the selected value from the list.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, url_for, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'a secret key'


@app.route('/fruits', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_fruit_selection():
    fruits = ["apple 1", "banana 1", "grapes", "orange", "broccoli", "carrot",
              "potato 1"]
    return render_template('fruit_selection.html', fruits=fruits)
```

`fruit_selection.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fruit selection page</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="carrier">
    {% for fruit in fruits %}
    {% if "1" in fruit %}
    <option value={{ fruit }}>
        {{ fruit }}
    </option>
    {% endif %}>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: output demo]